# Passing a parameter to a function that is added to a List

Tags: javascript, jquery

In below code I'm attempting to add a function `test` to an Array. The function `test` contains a parameter `param1` :

```
var param1 = "param1"

var fArr = []
fArr.push(test(param1));

for (var i = 0; i < fArr.length; i++) {
  fArr[i](param)
}

function test(param){
  console.log('param is '+param)
}
```

When I run this code I receive error :

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: param is not defined
```

How can I pass a parameter to the function that is added to array `fArr` ?

Comment: But if the parameter's name is `param1` why are you calling `param`?

Comment: `fArr[i]` is not a function, why are you trying to call it?

Comment: @Barmar is "test(param1)" not interpreted as a function?

Comment: When you put parentheses after a funtion name, it means to **call** the function, not return the function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not adding a function to the array. You're calling the function, and adding what it returns to the array. But the function doesn't return anything, so you're pushing `undefined` onto the array.

What I think you want is:

```
var param1 = "param1";

var fArr = [];
fArr.push(function() {
    test(param1));
});

for (var i = 0; i < fArr.length; i++) {
  fArr[i]();
}

function test(param){
  console.log('param is '+param);
}
```

P.S. Get out of the bad habit of omitting `;` at the end of statements.

Comment: `.push( test.bind(undefined,param1) )` as a alternative should also work - [partial function application](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

Comment: @birdspider That's slightly different, because it doesn't create a closure over the variable.

Comment: ah, true - I assume it would work here anyway because param1 is fixed - thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score -1):

The error is here: `fArr[i](param)`. You never initialized variable `param`.
Are you sure you do not want to use `param1`?